# The layout does not maintain its ratio when my app is run on a device or an emulator

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my xml code. The problem that I am encountering is that any layout element like a button or an imageview looks fine in preview mode... but when I run it on any device or an emulator... it does not maintain its ratio...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/im">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/display"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:id="@+id/display"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-330dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_button"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:id="@+id/b1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_button"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:id="@+id/b2"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_button"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:id="@+id/b3"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-301dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_button"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:id="@+id/b4"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_button"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:id="@+id/b5"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_button"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:id="@+id/b6"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-301dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_button"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:id="@+id/b7"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_button"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:id="@+id/b8"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_button"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:id="@+id/b9"/>


 </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Check if Android Definition in your IDE and you Emulator AVD / Device are same , for consistent look. Try not to use too hard coded values of margin and sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your implementation is that you have used absolute positions whereas ideally you should use relative positioning. I have pasted some code using a gridlayout. Make relevant changes and use accordingly. Let me know if it works for you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:background="#EDE7F6"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:background="#42A5F5"
            android:id="@+id/b1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:background="#42A5F5"
            android:id="@+id/b2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:background="#42A5F5"
            android:id="@+id/b3"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:background="#42A5F5"
            android:id="@+id/b4"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:background="#42A5F5"
            android:id="@+id/b5"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:background="#42A5F5"
            android:id="@+id/b6"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:background="#42A5F5"
            android:id="@+id/b7"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:background="#42A5F5"
            android:id="@+id/b8"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:background="#42A5F5"
            android:id="@+id/b9"/>

    </GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The problem persists but in a different manner.... Now the grid layout is situated at the center of the screen but is as small as it was earlier... and the blue colored text view is also situated at the horizontal center of the screen and vertically situated at the top of the screen.... but is abnormally large....

Comment: Paste a screenshot with my changes included for me to guide you further.

Comment: I have made changes to my response above. I hope it should work for you this time. Make relevant changes w.r.t the android:background for each of the views to incorporate your background.

Answer (score 0):

try just add max width and max height and 
     layout_weight="1"
to all the bars try
    gravity="center"
you must let the phone to make a size for the bars if you use 35dp size thats is not same in other android devices because the dp is known px size and the resoulation of phone is not thats why its its getting smaller in another phones.
u can use just Linear layout insted of grid layout.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000">

<Button
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_you_should_know"
    android:maxWidth="360dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="top|center">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_wounded_demon"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_maze_desert"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_working_with_darkness"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="top|center">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_weak_spot"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_none"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_none"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="top|center">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_none"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_none"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_none"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

its my layout in my app and its works for me hope work for u too.

sorry my english is not verygood.